# How can I refresh a picture on Windows photo viewer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-photo-viewer

I have opened a picture with Windows photo viewer. Another program changed it.  How can I refresh the picture on Windows photo viewer?

I don't see any button for it. I went through the menu and couldn't find any action for it. I tried <kbd>F5</kbd> as well as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, it didn't work.

I [read](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/20559/903):

> I have a script that outputs a PNG image. If I open the image in WPV from the explorer AND leave the explorer window open on that folder, then WPV updates in about half a second. Otherwise, WPV doesn't seem to notice updates to the file.

I would prefer not to have a Windows explorer window open just for that purpose.

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

[image]

Comment: I just tested it with Photo Viewer and MS Paint, and when I saved the image after editing it in Paint, Photo Viewer "refreshed" with the changed image right away. Are you doing something different?

Comment: @wysiwyg It looks like after a while the  Photo Viewer stops refreshing. Just like Windows explorer sometimes stops refreshing file lists, in which case one needs to hit F5 to refresh manually.

Comment: Well, the only thing I can think of is to add another (blank) image in the folder, and send Right/Left arrow key presses in quick succession, so Viewer refreshes.

Comment: @wysiwyg Thanks, sounds quite lame but I can't find better either. Feel free to post it as an answer to avoid the automatic deletion of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only workaround I can think of is to add another (blank) image in the folder, and send Right/Left arrow key presses in quick succession on a loop (via an [AHK](https://autohotkey.com/) script perhaps), to cycle to the blank image and back to your graph image, forcing Photo Viewer to refresh.

Alternatively, if it doesn't have to be Windows Photo Viewer, try [JPEGView](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jpegview/), as suggested on this thread: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2753/is-there-an-image-viewer-for-windows-that-auto-refreshes-the-image-when-it-is-mo

Comment: This is rather sad, given that auto-refresh was quite reliable in Windows 7's photo viewer.